# frames in a saved matplotlib animation are out of order

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I can produce an animation with matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation, displayed on screen.  When I save the animation as an mp4, however, the frames are "rotated" out of order.  Let's say the animation is 100 frames long.  Then saved animation shows the last 25 frames or so first, and then starts from the beginning and shows the rest of the frames.  I have tried exiting python and starting all over, to no avail.

I am just animating a series of line plots.  The relevant code is

```
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import animation

    # animation function.  This is called sequentially
    def animate(i,tscale,whichcomp,line):
        x = wv.x
        y = wv.hist[i*tscale]
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,

    # initialization function: plot the background of each frame
    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,

    # First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
    fig2 = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes()
    line, = ax.plot([], [], 'r-')
    plt.xlim((0,wv.x[-1]))
    plt.ylim((-1,1))

    plotsteps = 3

    # call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, animate, numsteps/plotsteps,
                                   fargs=(plotsteps,0,line), init_func=init,
                                   interval=20, blit=True)

    # save the animation as an mp4.
    anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.